# Angular 2+ directive - how to get nativeElement from child directive in the same or nested template

Tags: javascript, angular, directive, angular2-directives

I'm attempting to create a directive to manage ARIA Web accessible tab events using Angular 2+, but I'm having an issue with Angular Directives.

I want to have hierarchical directives so I can specify the parent and have access to child directives so I can bind the tabindex correctly.

I have a full example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyymog) if you need to refer to that.

As an example I have 3 directives. **AriaListBox**, **AriaLabel** & **AriaListItem**. **AriaListBox** is the parent containing an **AriaLabel** and a collection of **AriaListItems**.

I have been able to get a reference to the **AriaLabel** using `@ContentChild` but cannot do the same with `@ContentChildren` to get references for the **AriaListItem** directive.

From the **AriaListBox** I'm attempting to use the following which I believe should be set in the `ngAfterContentInit` event following the [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren#description).

```
@ContentChildren(Directive, { descendants: true }) public items: QueryList<Directive>;
```

#### AriaListBox

`src/aria/aria-listbox.directive.ts`

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[AriaListBox]',
})
export class AriaListBoxDirective implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChild(AriaLabelDirective) public label: AriaLabelDirective;
  @ContentChildren(AriaListItemDirective, { descendants: true })
  public listItems: QueryList<AriaListItemDirective>;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private searchService: SearchService) {}

  public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log('listItems', this.listItems);
  }
}
```

#### AriaLabel

`src/aria/aria-label.directive.ts`

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[AriaLabel]',
})
export class AriaLabelDirective {
  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {}
}
```

#### AriaListItem

`src/aria/aria-listitem.directive.ts`

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[AriaListItem]',
})
export class AriaListItemDirective {
  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {}
}
```

#### HTML

`src/search-link-list/search-link-list.component.html`

My HTML template uses the directives with the following.

```
<div AriaListBox>
  <h3 AriaLabel>{{ title$ | async }}</h3>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">
      <a href="{{ item.url }}" #link AriaListItem>{{ item.name }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is there anything I have missed? I have attempted to get a reference using a selector `@ContentChildren('AriaListItem')` or the same with `@ViewChildren(AriaListItemDirective)` and similarly `@ViewChildren('AriaListItem')` But since it's a directive and not a component it also doesn't work.

The `items$` are mocked inside the `search.service.ts` file and are rendered to the screen without any issue.

Edit --

If I inspect the **LinkListItemComponent** and the **ListBoxDirective** lifecycle events, I can see that the `#link` QueryList exists in the `SearchLinkListComponent::ngAfterContentInit` before the `AriaListBoxDirective::ngAfterContentInit`, so it seems that the Directive should have access to the content.

Thanks for any help!